# Modulo bias: How to compute statistical distance?

Tags: statistical-distance

Assume we have two uniform distributions $X=U(\mathbb{Z}_m)$ and $Y=U(\mathbb{Z}_n) \bmod m$, for $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$.

The statistical distance is defined as:
$$
\Delta(X, Y) = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{a \in \mathbb{Z}_m} | \Pr[X = a] - \Pr[Y = a] | \enspace.
$$

**Question:**
What is the statistical distance between $X$ and $Y$ expressed as a function of $m$ and $n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left|#1\right|}
$$

The statistical distance between $X=U(\Z_m)$ and $Y=U(\Z_n) \bmod m$ is
$$
\Delta(X, Y) = \abs{ \frac{(n \bmod m)^2}{mn} - \frac{n \bmod m}{n} } \enspace .
$$

### Proof

Writing out the definition, we have

$$
\Delta(X, Y) = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{a \in \Z_m} \abs{\Pr[X=a] - \Pr[Y=a]} \enspace.
$$

For $a \in \Z_m$, we have $\Pr[X=a] = 1/m$ and
$$
\Pr[Y=a] = \frac{n- (n \bmod m)}{nm} \text{ , if $a\geq n \bmod m$ ,} \\
\Pr[Y=a] = \frac{n- (n \bmod m) + m}{nm} \text{ , if $a < n \bmod m$ .}
$$

Denote $r = (n \bmod m)$. It follows that
$$
\Delta(X, Y) = \frac{1}{2} \left(
\left( \sum_{a \in \Z_m: a < r} \abs{\frac{1}{m} - \frac{n - r + m}{nm}} \right)
+
\left( \sum_{a \in \Z_m: a \ge r} \abs{\frac{1}{m} - \frac{n- r}{nm}} \right)
\right)
=
\frac{1}{2} \left(
r \abs{\frac{1}{m} - \frac{n- r + m}{nm}}
+
(m - r) \abs{\frac{1}{m} - \frac{n- r}{nm}}
\right)
= \abs{ \frac{r^2-rm}{nm} } \enspace.
$$